# Crashlytics NoClassDefFoundError: com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers

Tags: android, crashlytics

I get a project from other developer to fix minor issues in app, when I'm running my app on device I'm getting an error:

```
15142-15142/com.etripconcept E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers
        at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.<init>(Crashlytics.java:224)
        at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.<init>(Crashlytics.java:207)
        at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.<init>(Crashlytics.java:202)
        at com.etripconcept.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:16)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5163)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2061)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm new in Android development, so it may be stupid question, but Google doesn't say anything about it. I use Android Studio 1.2.2 on Win 8.1

Comment: can you confirm if this is a multiDex application, or requires multidexing? Many apps I know required to go into multidex compiling after adding crashlytics.